# Question on example on MSDN

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akfttx8c(v=VS.90).aspx example for VB to see how virtual function works but the example used on MSDN doesn't even have a sub main!

I tried playing around with it but can't get it working. Anyone have an idea on how it should be setup? Thanks!

Comment: -1 Question is nothing to do with Inheritance-Based Polymorphism

Comment: Yes I had a question on the "example" on how it was structured. 

I'm new at this and I'm learning to get a hang of the terminology and wording of programming. I'm still to get used to the writing of programmers on how they explain and detail their programs.

Comment: I know that but I suggest you re-word your question as it is misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following `Main`:

```
Module AppEntryPoint

    Sub Main()
        TestPoly()
    End Sub

End Module
```

And yes, that *should* have been obvious from the description in the MSDN article …

Comment: I had:

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        TestPoly()
        ShowTax()
    End Sub

but wasn't 100% sure but thanks for the verification.

Comment: I'm still new to programming. I guess it should be obvious but to me it wasn't that clean and cut.